# What is the discriminant of $R:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> What is the discriminant of $R:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ ?

The discriminant is defined as the determinant of the matrix $\left(tr(x_ix_j)\right)_{1\le i,j\le n}$ for any basis $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of $R$ as $\mathbb Z$-module

A basis is $\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\}$, but what is the trace for example $tr(1\cdot\sqrt{2})$. By definition it should be sum of the embeddings $\sigma_i:R\to \bar{\mathbb Z}$ i.e.

$tr(x)=\sum_i^n \sigma_i(x)$

(actually this is the definition, if we have a field instead of $R$, so I'm not sure whether the restriction is also called an embedding)

Or there's another definition, the discriminant of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ is (where $\alpha$ is integral) the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, but unfortunately our $\mathbb Z$ is extended by $2$ elements, is it still possible to apply this method ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly easy to compute the desired traces as long as you note that the embeddings (or whatever they are called) are determined by the values $\sigma_i(\sqrt{2})$ and $\sigma_j(\sqrt{3})$, which are both constrained to lie in $\{\pm \sqrt{2}\}$ and $\{\pm \sqrt{3}\}$, respectively.  Thus, for instance, two maps take $\sqrt{2}$ to itself and two maps take it to $-\sqrt{2}$.

It would be nice if $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}] = \Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ in order to compute via the minmal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, but it appears that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}\not\in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}]$.  Instead, if you use integer coefficients and powers of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, you only can get even multiples of $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}$

Comment: Exactly for second part I thought the same since $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$, but $x^4-10x^2+1$ has discriminant $147456$, and it should be $9216$

Comment: Well the first method gives the right answer, so that explains it